# Where to set a Command?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I  have seen two different ways to define the Commands

```
public DelegateCommand OpenCommand {get;set;}

public ViewModelConstructor()
{
   OpenCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenMethod);
}
```

Wheras other people decide to set it directly, as it is uncommon for a Command to change.

```
public DelegateCommand => new DelegateCommand(OpenMethod);
```

this seems a like a cleaner way to do it, but maybe it is expected to define them in the constructor so it is clear for other people.

**What are the conventions on where to define objects such as Commands that won't change during Runtime?**

Comment: I prefer the command to be defined where it's declared since it's more reasonable. There is no hard and fast "right" way though.

Comment: `public DelegateCommand OpenCommand  => new DelegateCommand(OpenMethod);` will create new instance of `DelegateCommand` on every call.

Comment: Vasily is correct. As an addendum, there is a also way to initialize a property once outside the constructor: `public DelegateCommand OpenCommand { get; } = new DelegateCommand(OpenMethod);` which avoids creating a new command instance every time the property getter is being invoked...

Comment: Haven't tought about that, thanks! As it seems that wanting to know about conventions hasn't liked, I may end up closing the question. Nonetheless thanks for the information to all of you!

Comment: If you like that sort of pattern.  You could use a private backer and a pattern like Figure 3: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vasily.sib mentions, the second method will create a new instance on each call.

I find the second method actually causes problems with the way `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` affects Views because of this. Consider the following ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private bool CanEx { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand XCommand => new DelegateCommand(X, Can);
    public DelegateCommand YCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand SwitchCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        CanEx = true;
        YCommand = new DelegateCommand(Y, Can);
        SwitchCommand = new DelegateCommand(Switch);
    }

    private void X(object obj) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X");

    private void Y(object obj) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Y");

    private bool Can(object obj) => CanEx;

    private void Switch(object obj)
    {
        CanEx = !CanEx;

        XCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        YCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

When I create a View from this ViewModel, with `Button`s for each command, the `Button` for `XCommand` will not show as disabled when I fire `SwitchCommand`.

This seems to have something to do with the fact that at the time when `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` is called, it is `null`.

Comment: That actually explains why I normally have issues with `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`. Totally missed it. Thanks!

Comment: With regard to your last paragraph, the reason why the "X" button does not disable is due to the fact that it uses a DelegateCommand whose RaiseCanExecuteChanged method is NOT being called. Note that when accessing the `XCommand` property, there is nothing being `null` there or has been disposed of. Rather, for each `XCommand` access, a new DelegateCommand is created. Thus, `XCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` is raising CanExecuteChanged event NOT on the DelegateCommand used by the "X" button, but rather raises it on a (new) DelegateCommand that is unrelated to the one used by the "X" button

Comment: That's only true for this your case. Usually the command source subscribes to the `ICommand.CanExecute` event. According to the pattern you have to explicitly implement the event setters and getters (add and remove) where your command hooks to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`event (e.g. `CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;`).

Comment: Now when ever you interact with a command source  (e.g. click a button) the `CommandManger` raises the `RequerySuggested` event, which in turn triggers the reevaluation of the can execute state and therefore invocation of all `CanExecut(object):bool` (since all command sources have implicitly subscribed to the `CommandManager` rather than to the `ICommand` directly. So when you follow this pattern you don't need to raise this event yourself. You shouldn't at all. Better raise `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` to force reevaluation.

Comment: The `XCommand`object will never be disposed as long the view that receives an instance of it continuous to live. Therefore it will never be NULL for the relevant depending object (command source).

Comment: To sum it up: the very moment the view (or command source to be more precise) receives an ICommand, it will subscribe to its `CanExecuteChanged` event - which delegates the subscription to the `CommandManager` - which calls `InvalidateRequerySuggested` - which raises `CanExecuteChanged` on the `ICommand` - which then invokes the `CanExecute` delegate to receive a boolean - on which the command source decides whether to disable or enable itself. From MSDN `ICommand`documentation: "Normally, a command source calls CanExecute on the command when this event [`ICommand.CanExecuteChanged`] occurs."

Comment: `DelegateCommand<T>.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` only invokes the `CanExecute` on the current command, which indeed can lead to unexpected behavior, when the programmer expects some automated behavior. This indeed requires the programmer to invoke `DelegateCommand<T>.RaiseCanExecuteChanged` for _all_ commands manually, since he now avoids the `CommandManager` which would automate this. Now when using the second approach of creating a new ICommand instance on each getter invocation, you have to be careful or introduce your own 'CommandManager'  logic in order to handle (notify) all those instances

Comment: But when sticking to the pattern and make use of the `CommandManager`, both approaches  are the same, since the differences are not noticeable (memory consumption, speed). The only difference is tthat the first approach shares the `CanExecuteChanged` event delegate among all command sources  whereas the second distributes a dedicated event delegate per command source.